# I accidentally submitted an unsigned Tier 4 Visa Application. What should I do?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, study, uk-visa

I had two applications and only one was signed. I submitted the unsigned visa application.

I am already on purchased priority service processing. It has been two days since my passport was submitted to UKVI. (5-10 working days guaranteed decision).

What should I do?! I supplied a electronic signature during biometrics, along with all possible supporting documents.

Will my visa be rejected/refused?

Comment: Call them and explain the situation. In any case, you're likely to get your processing delayed, not necessarily rejected.